# C# Constructor of class initialising and running script

Tags: c#

Got some strange behaviour with a script, the constructor of my `FileHandler` class appears to be calling the class and running the script.
The class itself is only being referenced in VS15 once and that is by its constructor, the main method has not yet even have an object of `FileHandler`, which is not mentioned anywhere else in the code.

Surely this code should not be running?

[image]

Edit: I placed a breakpoint at the start of the `Program.cs` and began stepping through, but when I did this I noticed that the `public class FileHandler` becomes `class Program` and my constructor is 'replaced' by a `Main` method.

Is this something that C# does by design?

[image]

`Programs.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using QuantConnect;
using QuantConnect.Securities;
using QuantConnect.Securities.Forex;

namespace TradingDaysFileChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var securityType = SecurityType.Forex;
            var ticker = TickType.Trade;
            var marketHoursDatabase = MarketHoursDatabase.FromDataFolder();
            var market = Market.FXCM;
            var symbol = Symbol.Create(ticker.ToString(), securityType, market);
            var marketHoursDbEntry = marketHoursDatabase.GetEntry(symbol.ID.Market, symbol.Value, symbol.ID.SecurityType);
            var exchange = new ForexExchange(marketHoursDbEntry.ExchangeHours);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
```

`FileHandler.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using QuantConnect.Securities.Forex;

namespace TradingDaysFileChecker
{
    public class FileHandler
    {

        private readonly StreamWriter _writeToFile;
        private readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> _missingDays;
        private readonly string _dataFilePath;
        private readonly DateTime _startDate;
        private readonly DateTime _endDate;
        private readonly ForexExchange _exchange;
        private readonly IEnumerable<DateTime> _validTradingDays;
        private readonly string[] _forexSecuritiesFolders;

        public FileHandler(ForexExchange exchange)
        {
            _startDate = new DateTime(2007, 04, 01);
            _endDate = new DateTime(2016, 07, 25);
            _exchange = exchange;

            _writeToFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\RichardsPC\Documents");
            _dataFilePath = @"C:\Users\RichardsPC\Desktop\export\exporter\forex\fxcm\minute\";
            _forexSecuritiesFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(_dataFilePath);

            _missingDays = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            _validTradingDays = IterateOverDateRange(_exchange, _startDate, _endDate);
        }

        public void CheckForMissingFiles()
        {
            foreach (var validDay in _validTradingDays)
            {
                foreach (var forexSecurity in _forexSecuritiesFolders)
                {
                    var fxPair = new DirectoryInfo(forexSecurity).Name;
                    var formattedDate = FormatDate(validDay);
                    var path = SetPath(_dataFilePath, fxPair, formattedDate);

                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        _missingDays.Add(Tuple.Create(fxPair, formattedDate));
                    }
                }
            }

            Results();
        }

        public void Results()
        {
            if (_missingDays.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var missingDay in _missingDays.OrderBy(md => md.Item1))
                {
                    var formattedTupleOutput = missingDay.ToString().TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')');
                    Console.WriteLine(formattedTupleOutput);
                    WriteResultsToFile(formattedTupleOutput);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                var noFilesMissing = "No results missing";
                Console.WriteLine(noFilesMissing);
                WriteResultsToFile(noFilesMissing);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Records missing: " + _missingDays.Count);
        }

        public void WriteResultsToFile(string result)
        {
            _writeToFile.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static string FormattedFileName(string tradingDay)
        {
            return tradingDay + "_quote.zip";
        }

        public string FormatDate(DateTime validDay)
        {
            return validDay.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }

        public static string SetPath(string dataFilePath, string fxPair, string formattedDate)
        {
            return dataFilePath + fxPair + @"\" + FormattedFileName(formattedDate);
        }

        public IEnumerable<DateTime> IterateOverDateRange(ForexExchange exchange, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            for (var day = start.Date; day.Date <= end.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
                if (exchange.IsOpenDuringBar(day.Date, day.Date.AddDays(1), false))
                {
                    yield return day;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that is running? The "Reference" is just the constructor (and that's normal)

Comment: Put a break point on code and then use menu : Debug : Windows : Call Stack to find methods that are calling the code.

Comment: Also that class should implement `IDisposable` - its holding on to a `StreamWriter`/`FileStream` -- and it needs to call `Dispose` on that StreamWriter

Comment: @EliArbel the script is running, the `Results()` method is being called and outputting to the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.
I had an old version of `TradingDaysFileChecker.cs` in the Documents folder of my system that I had backed up for some reason.
In that version all the file handling logic was inside `Program.cs`.
I refactored and extracted out the file handling to the new class.

For some reason when I was running the script, it was still using that old copy, even though it was not in the solution folder.
That's why the change in the class name and appeared to happen, it was jumping into the `Program.cs` and `Main` method of that other file, pulling it up from my Documents folder.
How that happened, I do not know.

I deleted the file from my Documents folder and now it is behaving correctly.